# Explain Function Mistake

Tags: python, function

I managed to write my first function. however I do not understand it :-)
I approached my real problem with a simplified on. See the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
from pyXSteam.XSteam import XSteam
steamTable = XSteam(XSteam.UNIT_SYSTEM_MKS) 
T1_T_in = [398,397,395]
T1_p_in = [29,29,29]
T1_mPkt_in = [2.2,3,3.5]
def Power(druck,temp,menge):
    H = []
    Q = []
    for i in range(len(druck)): 
        H.append(steamTable.h_pt(druck[i],temp[i]))
        Q.append(H[i]*menge[i])
    return Q

t1Q=Power(T1_p_in,T1_T_in,T1_mPkt_in)
t3Q = Power(T3_p_in,T3_T_in,T3_mPkt_in)
print(t1Q)
print(t3Q)
```

It works. The real problem now is different in that way that I read the data from an excel file. I got an error message and (according my learnings from this good homepage :-)) I added ".tolist()" in the function and it works. I do not understand why I need to change it to a list? Can anybody explain it to me? Thank you for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
from pyXSteam.XSteam import XSteam
steamTable = XSteam(XSteam.UNIT_SYSTEM_MKS) 

pfad="XXX.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(pfad)

T1T_in = df.iloc[2:746,1]
T1p_in = df.iloc[2:746,2]
T1mPkt_in = df.iloc[2:746,3]

def Power(druck,temp,menge):
    H = []
    Q = []
    for i in range(len(druck)): 
        H.append(steamTable.h_pt(druck.tolist()[i],temp.tolist()[i]))
        Q.append(H[i]*menge.tolist()[i])
    return Q

t1Q=Power(T1p_in,T1T_in,T1mPkt_in)

t1Q[0:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first example works is because you are passing the `T1_mPkt_in` variable into the `menge` parameter as a `list`:

```
T1_mPkt_in = [2.2,3,3.5]
```

Your second example is not working because you pass the `T1_mPkt_in` variable into the `menge` parameter as a `series` and not a `list`:

```
T1mPkt_in = df.iloc[2:746,3]
```

If you print out the type of `T1_mPkt_in`, you will get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

In `pandas`, to convert a `series` back into a `list`, you can call `.tolist()` to store the data in a `list` so that you can properly `index` it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I will consider this!